# IntelliJ debugger data views

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ has a [feature](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/04/type-renderers/) that lets you specify an expression to execute instead of `.toString()` when showing a textual representation of an object in the debugger.

Unfortunately, in my particular case, the operation I want to perform is not small enough to fit in a single expression (viz. iterating through an array, converting each of its elements to a string and joining those strings together). The object itself is defined in generated code, so adding a `.toPrettyString()` method is out of the question.

Is there any way to create a more complex debug view? Eclipse can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a way to perform complex debug operation in IntelliJ, but you can use a debug helper class containing static methods that will do the job and pass your instance to this method in the data type renderer...

Comment: Yep, this is the only way to do it. IntelliJ doesn't support this feature.